# Outlook 550 5.6.0 unacceptable content

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, email-bounces

A user is using Windows 7 / Outlook 2010 SP2 with emails going through a Jerseymail POP3 setup.

He is receiving a bounce back as soon as he clicks send -

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

550 5.6.0 Content unacceptable.

This has started a couple of days ago and not to all people he emails out to. Checking the content, there is nothing untoward.

I have had one occasion when I deleted the subject and typed it back in and the email sent, but I have not had this luck with others.

I seems like it is an Outlook issue as the Bounce backs are received very quickly.

Comment: So, why is that flagged outlook? The receiving server tells him his content is not welcome - that is not an outlook issue and should be taken up wih the server operators and admins to theck their content filtering. TOTALLY not outlook at fault here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did not make sense that emails sent to different people that have different content and are in completely different companies brings back the same issue.

Comment: It acutally may because it may be some 3rd party software thyey all use that flags you for some reason. Problem is - the 550 code with only this information tells you nothing so it is not helpfull for debugging.

Comment: Send the EXACT same email that gets a bounceback via OWA if you want to quickly determine if it is an Outlook/client issue or not.